# Does Accuracy work against naval units?

Tags: civilization-5

I guess it should. After all neither Coast nor Ocean is *Hills, Forrest or Jungle*. Right?

Comment: I vaguely recall it does, but am not 100%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does, accuracy contributes against targets in open terrain. Water tiles are considered open terrain.